# import specific columns from googlesheet using googlesheets4::read_sheet()

Tags: r, googlesheets4

I can read in all columns between columns A:O, but this can require indicating many column types that I do not care about.

```
library(googlesheets4)
library(tidyverse)

gs_ex <- 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<my_long_id>'

gs_raw <- 
  read_sheet(
    gs_ex, 
    sheet = 'Converted', 
    range = 'A:O', 
    col_types = 'cccDccDcDcDccD' # c = character, D = Date
  )
```

Can I only specify the 3 columns I do care about?

```
gs_raw <- 
  read_sheet(
    gs_ex, 
    sheet = 'Converted', 
    range = 'A,K,O', # this will not work
    col_types = 'cDD' 
  )
```

Comment: `range` can only a range of values either numeric or character i.e. `cell_cols`

Comment: Another potential option is to create a new googlesheet referencing the 3 columns of interest from the <my_long_id> sheet using the [IMPORTRANGE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340), then import that into R